# How can I add custom props to TablePagination ActionComponent?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I try to extend a data table component (material-table) to make it translatable. It uses its own component as `ActionComponent` prop, that has a few strings I like to translate.
I extended the the MTablePagination component to use translated strings from a prop named `localization`, but I'm not able to use it. The MTablePagination component is exported as hoc using material-ui `withStyles` method.
If I try to use the extended component it leads to the following error message:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
<WithStyles(MTablePaginationInner) />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?
```

The original TablePagination component is used like this:

```js
import MTablePagination from './m-table-pagination';
<TablePagination
  ...
  ActionsComponent={MTablePagination}
/>
```

Where I try to use the extended component like this:

```js
import MTablePagination from './m-table-pagination';
const localization={someKey: 'some value'};
const pagination = <MTablePagination localization={localization}/>
<TablePagination
  ...
  ActionsComponent={pagination}
/>
```

I'm quite new to material-ui and I think I misunderstood something, but I cannot find anything in the docs pointing me to the correct way...
What would be the correct way to give the `ActionComponent` own props?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have to answer one of my questions again... material-table has been enhanced with an icon props, that has the same need of adding custom props to the `ActionComponent` prop...

They solved it using the component as function like:

```js
ActionsComponent={(subProps) => <MTablePagination {...subProps} icons={props.icons}/>}
```

I'll try to adapt this solution...

-- edit: add final code ---

```js
import MTablePagination from './m-table-pagination';
const localization={someKey: 'some value'};
const pagination = <MTablePagination localization={localization}/>
<TablePagination
  ...
  ActionsComponent={(subProps) => <MTablePagination {...subProps} icons={props.icons} localization={localization}/>}
/>
```